# How to create LOC data in git?

Tags: git, metrics, lines-of-code

I want to track the improvement of a project over time in git.

I need line of code statistics by time. For example.

```
Time        LOC
-----       -----
01/01/2015 29021
01/08/2015 29987
......
```

gitstats is throwing some weird error. So I need another alternative.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the start of an idea.

You could have a little script which checks out a ref, and outputs all non-binary code content with:

```
#!/bin/sh
# catAll.sh
git checkout $1;
for i in `git grep --cached -Il ''`; do
    cat $i
done
```

Then, pipe that output to `wc` to get the LOC:

```
catAll.sh | wc -l
```

Get the date of a commit with:

```
git show -s --format=%ci <sha>
```

Then, (and this could take long time to run depending on the size of your repo) run the command with `HEAD`, `HEAD~`, `HEAD~~`, etc.

This would involve a little scripting to put it all together, but could be wrapped in a nice command to spit out the last, say 5, commit points.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc .

I used to use it when it was on Sourceforge and found it very useful. If you *must* let yourself be ruled by metrics. ;-)

Comment: For research purposes, really:)